# angular dependency injection of one service into another for route guard

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-routing, angular-services, angular-router-guards

In my angular app I have two services, one deals with the http layer, and the other is simply a route guard to implement the `canActivate` method related to the status of the first service. For example:

backend.service:

```
@Injectable()
export class BackendService {
    private data: any;
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('backend service constructor hit');
        this.data = 'initial';
    }
    getData() {
        console.log(this.data);
        return this.data;
    }
    setData(data) {
        // http stuff
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

routeguard.service:

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteguardService implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private backendService: BackendService) { }
    canActivate() {
        return this.backendService.getData() !== 'initial';
    }
}
```

I believe I am providing one of the services in the wrong location? Currently I have both services in the `providers` array of my `app.module`. But I can tell with the console.log statements that the `backend.service` is being new'd up separately when it gets called as part of the routing versus when a component uses it, so the data is different and the data always comes back as 'initial' when checked in the canActivate method despite having it set to something else from a component. Hope I explained that clearly, I'm still new to angular.

Do I need to provide one of the services in a different location or am I doing something else wrong entirely? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: The question doesn't contain all relevant code. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . With a component and a module you're referring to.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 module in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the problem was that I accidentally also included the `backend.service` in the root `app.component` providers, which meant that sub components of that would have one instance injected, however the one in my routes file was injected from `app.module` providers instead, thus the duplicate services and discrepancy in data.

So the solution was to remove the service from the `app.component` and always have it be provided by `app.module` instead.

Comment: Just to point out, everytime you inject this service anywhere in your app, it will create a new data property associated to it as part of the constructor call. Just be aware of it, if that is desired, then no issues. Otherwise, or in other words, if you wanna have a singleton-property associated with your injectable service that can be accessed from within multiple modules, then you will have to declare it with `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the property you want to set in `BackendService` as a `static` one. Then use getters and setters to access it. Don't initialize it in the `constructor` of the service.

```
@Injectable()
export class BackendService {
    private static data: any = 'initial';
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('backend service constructor hit');
    }
    get data() {
        console.log(this.data);
        return BackendService.data;
    }
    set data(data: any) {
        // http stuff
        BackendService.data = data;
    }
}
```

You can then access the private static `data` value outside using the getters and setters. Like for example in the `canActivate` guard,

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteguardService implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private backendService: BackendService) { }
    canActivate() {
        return this.backendService.data !== 'initial';
        // this.backendService.data <-- denotes getter
        // this.backendService.data = 'not-initial'; <-- denotes setter
    }
}
```

You are providing the services in the right places as understood from the question. Try and see if this fixes it.